# How do I submit disabled input in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, asp.net-mvc

How do I submit disabled input in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Generally you need to phrase your question as a question and then post the answer separately. Voting to close; recommend you move the 'answer' part to an actual answer.

Comment: I believe @Dhaval post is exactly answer because of disabled word in your question.

Comment: Check This: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/How-to-submit-disabled-input-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Thanks to everyone:

The way i resolved this:

```
document.getElementById("Costo").readOnly = true;
document.getElementById("Costo").style.color = "#c0c0c0";
```

Note:

I got this information on the answer but i got editted.

Comment: This didn't quite work for me (figured it out thanks to **[this SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833884/why-does-a-read-only-textbox-does-not-return-any-data-in-asp-net)**). This worked: ```textBox.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");``` and the explanation is in the link

Comment: That's good that you edited it as this is making more sense for me.

Comment: readonly seems to be way to go. It doesn't do weird things like not posing the control back but doesn't allow to edit it. Muchas Gracias!

Comment: To add to Michael Brennt's comment, if you're using jQuery the second line becomes `$("#textBoxId").css("color", "#c0c0c0")`.

Answer (score 195):

Can't you make the field `readonly="readonly"` instead of `disabled="disabled"`? A readonly field value will be submitted to the server while still being non-editable by the user. A `SELECT` tag is an exception though.

Comment: readonly works but it doesn't gray out the field. Here is an example I am using: `<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.p1, new { @readonly = "readonly" }) %>` how can I gray it out so visually it looks like it is not editable. Better yet can we use something similar to LabelFor, I tried LabelFor but it only gets the DisplayName....

Comment: 4 years doing .net asp and I never knew that disabled inputs don't get poste back... how did that pass me? Just include a Hidden field for the disabled select and its all sorted.(Even though the ID's are repeated on the form which is not allowed)

Comment: This doesn't work for `type="checkbox"` inputs either

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing with radio buttons but readonly doesn't seem to work on them.

Answer (score 35):

@ppumkin mentioned this on his comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2701907/526704) but I wanted to highlight it as I was unable to find other resources on submitting data from a disabled `<select>`. I also believe it is relevant to the question as selects are not `<input>`s but they are "input"s.

> Just include a Hidden field for the disabled select and its all sorted.

Example:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedID, ... , new { disabled = "disabled"}) @* Won't be posted back *@
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SelectedID) @* Will be posted back *@
```

**Caution:** this will put two tags on the page with the same ID, which is not really valid HTML and could cause headaches with javascript. For me, I have javascript to set the value of the dropdown by its html `id`, and if you put the hidden field first, the javascript will find that instead of the `select`.

Answer (score 23):

Typically, if I have a field that is "read-only" but needs to be submitted back to the server, I will make the display disabled (or simply text), but then add a hidden field with the same name.  You still need to make sure that the field is not actually modified on the server-side -- just don't update it from the model in your action -- but the model state will still be accurate if there are errors.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of doing what you're sugesting. But I would had to handle more variables.

I'm hopping that may be my post will appear in google and people won't have to suffer, looking for an easy solution.

Comment: One problem with your solution is that it breaks if javascript is disabled. Injecting the hidden field server-side doesn't have this issue.

Answer (score 19):

You can also use code like this before the form submits:

```
$(":disabled", $('#frmMain')).removeAttr("disabled");
```

Comment: I used this, don't need to worry about hidden elements, not sure if there are any disadvantages, except maybe slight delay on post back due to js function

Comment: Against many of answers that mentioned about using read-only rather disabled I believe in many cases we need to use disabled, I read about 15 answers in similar questions and chose this just with own jQuery filter to select appropriate elements to remove disabled attribute, great thanks.

Comment: What if you are submitting with `Ajax.BeginForm`?

Comment: use OnBegin "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.onbegin(v=vs.118).aspx"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/dd460351(v%3dvs.118)

Comment: looks a little odd, but it was the only solution that worked for me ...

Comment: Absolutely gorgeous solution !

Comment: The most perfect solution. Should be marked as Answer.

Answer (score 13):

By design browsers do not support that.

Either make them `readonly` which allows submitting values to server
or if you're dealing with controls that are still usable with `readonly` attribute such as Select, add css style `pointer-events: none;` to make them non-interactive

Kind of a hack, but works! It also works when you are submitting form directly with submit button without using javascript. No extra work required!

Eg:

```
<select asp-for="TypeId" 
   asp-items="@(new SelectList(await TypeRepository.FetchTypesAsync(), "TypeId", "Name"))"
   class="form-control form-control-sm" 
   readonly 
   style="pointer-events: none;">
</select>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can create an editor template like the one below

CSS

```
.disabled {
    background-color:lightgray;
}
```

Editor Template

```
@model string
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x,new {@class="disabled", @readonly=true })
```

Answer (score 3):

This will help in submit model values in ASP.net:

```
$("#iD").attr("style", "pointer-events: none;background-color:rgb(220,220,220)");
```

Comment: Please [format your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). this makes it more readable for everybody

Answer (score 2):

when we are dealing with disabled but checked checkboxes and we want to post the value, we need to ensure our hidden field appears before the @Html.CheckBoxFor hidden field.

following is the link from where I found the answer.
http://davecallan.com/posting-disabled-checkboxes-mvc-razor-views/#comment-11033

Answer (score 2):

I usually use this way for CheckBox or CheckBoxFor because making it disabled is causing the losing the value. Readonly doesn't work on checkbox neither.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Order.Transfer)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Order.Transfer)
```

Comment: This helped me for creating a read only "Review" page from which the posting happens on click of Submit button. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

expanding Tasos' (":disabled", $('#xxxForm')).removeAttr("disabled"); you can use:

```
$("#xxxForm").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = this;
    $('#Field1')[0].disabled = false;
    $('#Field2')[0].disabled = false;
    ...
    $('#FieldN')[0].disabled = false;
    form.submit(); // submit bypassing the jQuery bound event
});
```

Comment: see answer by @tasos $(":disabled", $('#frmMain')).removeAttr("disabled");

Answer (score 1):

Just put this script in @section scripts in your page.
this will enable inputs when you submit the page, and you should redirect user to another page after submit.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js">
$("form").submit(function () {
                    if ($('form').valid()) {
                        $("input").removeAttr("disabled");
                    }
                });
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

Just make that property [Required] in the ViewModel linked to that view.