# In a C# MVC app is it possible to submit variables from a web page in controls that did not change?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a C# MVC application and a `<form>` in my `page.cshtml` file. In that form I have `<input type="text" ... />` elements. If I submit this form I only get the values in `Response.Params` or `Response.Form` from the inputs where I changed the value manually (i.e. Entered the text box then typed something).

If I change the value with jQuery, `$('#myInput').val('some value');` this does not count as a change in the input's value and I do not get `myInput`'s value when I submit the form.

Is there any way to make sure **all** inputs are submitted? If not then is there a good workaround for this, maybe in some event that occurs before my model gets bound? I need to know all the input values from the form when submitted whether they changed or not.

**Some additional info:**

The form and other values are getting submitted correctly and I am receiving my model when the POST action is called in my controller.

The real issue is when my model is being bound. It is being created and bound with all values except the one not being submitted because it is not in the `Request.Params` collection.

Comment: That should not happen.  Show us your HTML.

Comment: Just accept the model as a parameter on your Action and you can use as-is.

Comment: Strange, I have never seen this. It always posts value regardless of how the were changed, or if they even changed at all

Comment: Have you looked in Fiddler to see how the values are being submitted?

Comment: Is your controller action receiving a model object or a more generic FormCollection?

Comment: Actually I seem to remember disabling fields caused them not to POST, are you doing this?

Comment: @musefan, that's it! Never would have put the two together. I am disabling the field and I need to have it disabled. Can I specify somewhere that disabled fields should still be submitted or do I have to enable it right before I submit the form?

Comment: @MikeWebb: I have added an answer which explains a technique that I have used to solve this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have only ever seen this behaviour when a field is disabled. Due to this, I commonly have a javascript function that handles the form submission and re-enables them on submit, this way the correct values get sent to the server.

Something like this does the trick for me (NOTE: I am using JQuery):

```
$(document).ready() {
    $("#ButtonSubmit").click(SubmitForm);
}

function SubmitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //ensure fields are enabled, this example does text and checkbox types
    $("[type='text']").attr("disabled", false);
    $("[type='checkbox']").attr("disabled", false);

    //submit the form
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

I am unaware of any easier way to do this, it would be nice if you could 'flag' something that instructs all fields to be submitted. But I don't know if this exists, maybe somebody else can offer a better solution.

**EDIT**: It appears that disabled fields not submitting is just the nature of HTML, and is not something that is tied to MVC.

---

It seems that if you make the fields `readonly` instead of `disabled` then the values will still submit. However, with this approach you lose the 'disabled' styling. The exception to this rule is `select` control, it seems this will not submit under `readonly` either. [More information on this can be in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700696/how-do-i-submit-disabled-input-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Thanks, musefan. It's still a pretty simple solution.

Comment: thanks for your extra research. Using `readonly` actually works perfectly. I have my own styling for disabled/readonly elements anyway.

Comment: @MikeWebb: No worries, I was keen to learn a bit more about this too

Answer (score 0):

Try using the razor helper to build the form tag.

@using(Html.BeginForm()) {
    ..

```
// make sure this is a submit button
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
```

}

In your controller action post method make sure you decorate it [HttpPost].
e.g.,

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(YourModel model) {

}

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue, this just shows how to submit a form. Which the OP seems to already be able to do. Also, please format your code correctly

Comment: @Tib, the issue is actually not at the Controller/Action level. The issue is that the value is not in the `Request.Params` collection which is sent to the server and used to build the model that is passed to the Action. The resulting Model in my case is incomplete because I am not receiving all the input values from the form submit.