# TextBoxFor value not passed to model when disabled

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a disabled input-field displaying data from a model.

```
<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.first_name, "Förnamn", new
            {
                @for = "inputFirstname",
                @class = "col-lg-3 control-label"
            })
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.first_name, new
                {
                    @type = "text",
                    @class = "form-control",
                    @id = "inputFirstname",
                    text = Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.first_name),
                    disabled="disabled"
                })
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I can submit this data to a controlelr method:

[HttpPost]

```
public ActionResult Index(RegistrationModel RegistrationModelViewModel)
{}
```

When i add `disabled="disabled"` the first_name data is null, if i remove it i get the correct data.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Ask yourself why you'd expect data from a disabled field to passed to the model in the first place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I submit disabled input in ASP.NET MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700696/how-do-i-submit-disabled-input-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Check This: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/How-to-submit-disabled-input-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to use **readonly** property, if you want to also display the data:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.first_name, new
    {
        @readonly = "readonly"
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an `<input type="hidden" name="whateverName" />` on the page which matches the disabled field. By default, it will not be sent to the server.