# How to get selected text from mvc disabled dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my mvc dropdwon i am not getting selected text for dropdown which is disabled

```
@Html.DropDownList("ServiceID", ViewBag.Services as SelectList, "Select Service", new { @class ="form-control" ,name="ServiceID",disabled="disabled"})
```

And my jquery

```
var selectedText = $("#ServiceID option:selected").text();
```

Comment: no duplication of value

Comment: Please set element as readonly instead of disabled. Refer :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700696/how-do-i-submit-disabled-input-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: `no duplication of value` - No idea what you mean by that. Please check the linked post as it uses a hidden field to track the selected value.

Comment: @J-Mean Please see last note on your linked post in regards to using readonly on a select `A SELECT tag is an exception though.` Meaning a `select` tag will not be readonly as you can still select values even though it has the attribute, even if applying the readonly attribute to the option tags as well.► [http://plnkr.co/edit/9T3wxSfhml7r4FRJeL5a?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/9T3wxSfhml7r4FRJeL5a?p=preview)

Comment: @Fran Thanks got to know something new.

Comment: Thank u it is working fine – Fran

Comment: Check This: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/How-to-submit-disabled-input-in-ASP-NET-MVC