# How to use an optional, generic parameter on a controller action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, generics, parameters, asp.net-mvc-controller

I am working with a BaseController that is used for a variety of entities. They may have `int` or `string` primary keys, represented by `<TPk>`.

E.g.:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create(TPk id)
{
    return View();
}
```

Everything is fine until I try and use `TPk` as an ***optional*** parameter.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create(TPk id = default(TPk))
{
    return View();
}
```

It seems that the 'optional' part isn't working.

So `/controller/create/2` is fine, but  `/controller/create` gives me the following error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Create(Int32)'

The optional works fine with an `int` or `string` id.  I can call `/controller/create/2` AND `/controller/create`.

But using a generic type argument `TPk`, the parameterless route no longer works.

---

### What I've Tried

I have tried making the `TPk` parameter nullable, but it won't compile:

> The type 'TPk' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable'

---

I have tried changing the parameter name from `id` to `altId` as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34863167/asp-net-mvc-why-is-my-view-passing-null-models-back-to-my-controller/34864052) - no joy

---

I have tried calling the same method, in exactly the same way, but with non-generic parameters. E.g.:

```
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Create(int id = default(int))
```

This worked fine.

---

I have tried creating a simple new project to isolate this code. (Shown below). This still gives problems with the parameterless version.

---

### Simple Code Test

**Controller**

```
public abstract class BaseController<TPk> : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Create(TPk id = default(TPk))
    {
        return View();
    }
}


public class NewsController : BaseController<int>
{

}
```

**Entity Classes**

```
public class BaseDataModel<TPk>
{
    public TPk Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class PageDataModel : BaseDataModel<string>
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

public class NewsDataModel : BaseDataModel<int>
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net conventions are heavily based on reflection. So this might explain the behavior. I have not tested if it realy does not work, but I am sure at this state you already tried to create a new project (POC) to preclude any custom code.

Maybe it can be fixed by looking deeper into the routing (method selection) and ModelBinder source code...

I would just create a different `DuplicateRecord` action instead.

If you do not understand your method without this comment, it is a good indication, that your current code probably smells anyway. (You are doing to much at the same thing):

```
// duplicates existing record if id is passed in, otherwise from scratch
```

Extract the shared things to another method (maybe even a service class) and have for each difference a seperate method.

---

That said, the idea of a generic CrudController is lovely, I tried this myself some years ago. But in trying so I have introduced all sort of generic parameters, strategy patterns, event delegates to make all possibilities possible.

- What happens if you need a join?
- What happens if you need a transaction?
- How do you handle errors?
- What happens if your crud logic needs 1, 2, 3 ... additional parameters to decide what to do?
- Soft Delete / Hard Delete?
- Cascade Delete / Restrict Delete?
- What happens if you ...

I have written so much code, it was blessing to revert to the good old non generic code. And if abstracted away in a service, the ActionMethods realy do not need to get big.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateProduct(CancellationToken ct, ProductCreateModel model)
{
    var result = await _productService.CreateAsync(model, ct);    
    //create response with some helpers... probably some ActionFilters
}
```

Generics can work ofcorse in a simple crud mapping where each View has exact one Entity, but it does not scale very well. So beaware and think twice about what you realy want ;)

Comment: Thanks! I probably will use a `DuplicateRecord` action, but I would like to understand why this is not working, if at all possible. I will post the answer if I ever find it...  I appreciate the generic CRUD warning, I know this to be true. This is my 3rd or 4th iteration of this pattern and I have only just ironed out the wrinkles to create a solution I can work with.

Comment: "Asp.net conventions are heavily based on reflection. So this might explain the behavior."  Would you be able to expand on this at all?

Comment: Not sure, what specific I should expand. With *this might explain the behavior*, I actually mean, reflection can introduce all kind of bugs one would not expect. In this case it seems for example, that generics are not handled correct. Take a look in the [DefaultModelBinder](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultModelBinder.cs) for example. Half the code is reflection.